# Drop down terminal in Unity

Tags: 14.04, command-line, unity, software-installation, software-recommendation

I want to implement drop down terminal feature in **Ubuntu 14.04** in **Unity** desktop environment. Is **Guake** suitable for Unity desktop environment? If not please refer me an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is suitable. Alternatives:

- Tilda (used to be somewhat unmaintained),
- XFCE Terminal and Terminator (both of which can be configured to act as drop-down terminals)
- Yakuake will have a rather large set of dependencies, but aside from that it should work fine too.

Comment: So using guake is best?

Comment: @SubhadipRoy "best" is for you to decide. I use Terminator, one of my friends use Guake and a third uses Yakuake.

Comment: Thanks....Actually my main concern was whether Guake would work for Unity because everywhere I was reading it works for Gnome.

Comment: Unity is based on GNOME.